# Change QGroupBox's content background

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qt5.5

I want to change the background of a QGroupBox, however I would like to only change the inside background (the darker shade of gray below each QGroupBox's title) as shown here:
[image]
What I currently have is

```
QGroupBox {
    background-color: red;
    border: 3px dashed black;
}
```

which changes the background of the entire QGroupBox like this:
[image]

Is there a way in Qt to only change the "interior box" background rather than the whole container? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to change the stylesheet of the inner group box; not the outer one I believe.

Comment: The picture is kindof misleading because it has two groupboxes but if you focus on the titles "Completeness" and "sub-criteria" you'll see where it is supposed to color (under the title) and where it colored (includes the title)

Comment: Oh you just need to add `margin-top: 1ex;` to the stylesheet to leave space for the title then. Sorry; I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there are 2 QGroupBox'es involved here, since that is not really clear from your post. Or is there a group box and some other inner container widget?

In either case you should be able to use stylesheets like following:

```
QGroupBox {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:1em;
}
QGroupBox QGroupBox {
    background-color: green;
}
QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: left top;
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
}
```

This will give you following result:

[image: Example]

You can of course replace the inner group box by an arbitrary widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using "setStyleSheet" function of widgets.

Get the inner group box object. And set the background color using "setStyleSheet" function.

Pseudo Code:

```
QGroupBox *innerGBox = new QGroupBox();

innerGBox->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
```

To know more about setting styles programmatic , refer below link.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Qt a little more about the kind of style you want, specifically the margins. Playing around a little with this code should give you the desired results:

```
QGroupBox {
    background-color: red;
    border: 3px dashed black;
    margin-top: 1ex; /* leave space at the top for the title */
}

QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
```

Take a look at the [Stylesheet examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)